# Unable to create new project with pulumi

Tags: pulumi

Followed the documentation https://www.pulumi.com/docs/quickstart/aws/create-project/ and could not get it working. npm install step fails.

I have tried with node version : v10.15.3 and npm version : 6.4.1

The error I get

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @pulumi/docker@^0.17.0
```

Expected the doc to be up-to-date with a FAQ link to common problems.

Comment: That's unexpected... `@pulumi/docker` version `0.17.0` [does exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pulumi/docker/v/0.17.0). Could this be a temporary glitch? Does it happen consistently when you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, does seem to happen consistently

Comment: Ok, Happened to have some entries ~/.npmrc overriding registry value for other namespaces. Changing it worked.